# Model predictions: how to manipulate dummy variables across time?

Tags: r, prediction, predict, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to predict insect populations across a year. I've built my model (a GAM, using the package mgcv). I then used the `predict()` function after I built a dummy dataset to build this prediction off of . This is where I'm struggling.

My question is: how can I build a new dummy dataset that will simulate, say cold winters vs. warm winters? I have just a "temperature" parameter, and I'm not sure how to manipulate that through time (or seasons). Ideally, I'd like to create a cold winter with mean summer temperatures and a warm winter with mean summer temperatures. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Quickly, my smoothing parameters in the model are: Average temperature, humidity, and day of year (doy). I have three random effect parameters in the model too. My model, prediction, and graph generated are below.

```
 m1 <- gam(total ~ s(temp.avg) + s(humid) + s(doy, bs="cc", k=5) + 
                s(trap, bs="re")+s(site, bs="re")+s(year, bs="re"), 
                family=nb(),gamma=1.4,method="REML",data=dfe)
    N <- 200
    M <- 365
    pdat1 <- with(dfe, expand.grid(year = c("2013","2014","2015","2016","2017"),
                                  humid = mean(humid, na.rm = TRUE),
                                  temp.avg = mean(temp.avg, na.rm = TRUE),
                                  doy = seq(min(doy), max(doy), length = M),
                                  trap = c("a","b","c","d"),
                                  site = c("A","B", "C", "D")))

pred1 <- predict(m1, newdata = pdat1, type = "response", se.fit=TRUE)
crit <- qt(0.975, df = df.residual(m1)) # ~95% interval critical t
pdat1 <- transform(pdat1, fitted = pred1$fit, se = pred1$se.fit)
pdat1 <- transform(pdat1,
                  upper = fitted + (crit * se),
                  lower = fitted - (crit * se))
ggplot(pdat1, aes(x = doy, y = fitted)) +
  geom_line() + theme_classic()+
  labs(y = "Predicted Population", x = "Day of Year") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of "can I estimate a time varying seasonal effect in R with GAMM?" . It's also lacking any data unless `dfe` is a dataset in some package or another.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't frame this question in the best way. The GAM is more or less irrelevant here - my question lies with the predict() function. How would I split up the temperature variable by season to accommodate different temperatures at different times of the year? I thought about using subset(), but I'm not sure how to apply that when building a new dummy dataset. Does this help clear-up my question?